# Android custom progressbar in each RecyclerView item slow down the UI

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

custom progressbar in each recyclerview item hang the UI when progress start how can i smooth the progress without hanging or stoping or slowing down the UI ?

I am using intentservice to download media and broadcast receiver to update the UI.

```
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int percentDownloaded = intent.getIntExtra(CacheDownloadService.BROADCAST_PAYLOAD_DOWNLOAD_PERCENT, -1);
        String downloadingUrl = intent.getStringExtra(CacheDownloadService.BROADCAST_PAYLOAD_DOWNLOAD_URI);


        if (getListView() != null) {
            if (getListView().getAdapter() != null && getListView().getAdapter() instanceof ListAdapter) {
                ListAdapter listAdapter = (ListAdapter) getListView().getAdapter();
                listAdapter.updateTrackDownloadProgress(downloadingUrl, percentDownloaded);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: How are you using progressbar in recyclerview ? You need to use broadcast receiver or listener(interface) which have a result call back in which you can update your progressbar.

Comment: yes i am using broadcast receiver to update the progress . all things are going well but whenever progress start it slow down the UI or i can not scroll recyclerview smoothly it hangs .

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: Are you updating progress bar in `runonUIThread` ? Also is recylerview in `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: i have updated my post please check the code i have posted how i update the UI of my recyclerview list adapter.

Comment: Its on main thread. Update your adapter in _runonUIThread_

Comment: still not solved after updating the adapter in runonUIThread.